# Передать переменную через .ajax()

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Как правильно передать jquery переменную через параметр data в .ajax() . И как правильно поймать её со стороны php?

Comment: [наслаждайтесь][1]


  [1]: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: {
       param1: value1, 
       param2: value2, 
       extendedExample: "myValue",
       associativeArrayValue: {
            arraykey1: arrayval1,
            arraykey2: arrayval2
       },
       numericalArrayValue: [9,8,7, "foo", "bar"],
       string: "myString"
    } 
    ...
})
```

**Обработка на стороне РНР** (к примеру передавали мы все это POST'ом):

```
$data = $_POST;
$data['param1'];
$data['param2'];
$data['extendedExample'];
$data['associativeArrayValue']['arraykey1'];
$data['associativeArrayValue']['arraykey2'];
$data['numericalArrayValue'][0];
$data['numericalArrayValue'][1];
$data['string'];
```

А в общем, в [Документации](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) искали?